# Android sql lite get count returns 1

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

this is my select code in database class
I've run this code when database was empty , when it had one row and when it had more than one row But at all conditions get row return 1 !
Thanks for any help 
code :

```
public int select(String table, String column, String record)
{
    int DataCount=0;
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+table+" WHERE "+column+"='"+record+"'  ", null);
    DataCount=c.getCount();
    return DataCount;

}
```

Comment: due to where condition only matched row will be returned

Comment: @PavneetSingh Due to the `Count` function only one row will be returned

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah cuz count will return the matched rows count only due to where clause only one match is found so count result in 1

Comment: @PavneetSingh Sorry I didn't get what you mean , would you please explain it more or give a solution ?

Comment: @Farhad try query without `where`  clause and see the difference and for better support please also mention in post what exactly the behavior you expect

Comment: @PavneetSingh I think you are wrong, The count SQL function will only return `one` row independent of the `where` clause

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: @PavneetSingh as per the link you gave, `try it` at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_count_all - It returns ONE row

Comment: @ScaryWombat i know , it will return only one row but question is a confused one , OP said even when there are two rows the result of query is one row he is confused with count and where clause , that's why i also mentioned to OP to be clear what he expects to happen

Comment: why i got negative point ! :(  ???

Comment: The reason `as per my answer` is that he is using the `getCount` method which returns the number of rows returned.

Comment: @PavneetSingh would you please vote up for this question? 
someone gave negative point and now I've been blocked for asking question

Comment: @ScaryWombat  would you please vote up for this question? someone gave negative point and now I've been blocked for asking question

Answer (score 1):

The `Count` function along with other similar functions such as `SUM` and `AVG` only return one row.

The `c.getCount()` method that you are calling returns the number of rows returned, not the value of it.

If you want the value of the row then use

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)

e.g.

```
int val = c.getInt (0);
```

Comment: Farhad, is this answers your question please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer